# Error when running psql command in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh (psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I used to use a script (`/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh`) to loop through database dumps in a folder copied into the postgres container and restoring them. It used to work nicely but recently it stopped working.

I get following error:

```
postgres_server_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh
postgres_server_1  | --> db_init.sh: Found /dumps/dataset_1.dump as dataset_1
postgres_server_1  | psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
postgres_server_1  |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
postgres_server_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The `db_init.sh` script loops through a folder containing database dumps and checks if the database exists already. If not it restores the dump.

`/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh` content:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in /dumps/*.dump;
do
    db_name=${i##*/}
    db_name=${db_name%.dump}
    echo "--> db_init.sh: Found $i as $db_name"

    if psql -U postgres -h localhost -lqt | cut -d \| -f 1 | grep -qw ${db_name}; then
        echo "--> db_init.sh: Database ${db_name} already exists."
    else
        echo "--> db_init.sh: Setting up database: ${db_name}"
        createdb -U postgres -h localhost-T template0 ${db_name}
        psql -U postgres -h localhost ${db_name} < ${i}
    fi
done
echo "--> db_init.sh: Setup complete."
```

I am using docker-compose to start the postgres container (and some others).

The `docker-compose.yml` content:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres_server:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ./data/dumps:/dumps:ro
      - ./scripts/db_init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

Now what I don't understand is why there seems to be a connection error usually associated with trying to connect to a postgres database from a different machine or container. But the script itself is running in the postgres container and a volume connects the directory containing the dumps into the container.
Running the `psql` command from within the container using `docker exec -it container_name bash` works fine and the dumps are there. Why do the `psql` commands work when executing them manually from within the container but not when executed via `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like [this commit](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/commit/8b63de5f0c8b6e9f51e45c64a4af561ef4e7bbf3#diff-60713fb19f6c50a2473835df63ff17f9) has broken your script.

Explanation:

PostgreSQL may accept connections not only via TCP/IP, but also via UNIX socket. The `-h localhost` argument tells `psql` to use TCP connections rather than UNIX socket.

If you look into the current [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/eff90effc6b5578be90bef93d96b3fceb1082a7c/docker-entrypoint.sh#L111) version, you will see, that during the execution of scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` PostgreSQL listens only on the UNIX socket, and the startup log says:

```
LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

This means that `psql -h localhost` will not connect to the database, as PostgreSQL does not listen on IP socket. You must use `psql` *without* `-h localhost` option to make it use UNIX socket instead of TCP connections.

But why running `psql -h localhost` manually works?

If you look into the `docker-entrypoint.sh` again, you will see that when all init scripts are executed, PostgreSQL is being [stopped](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/eff90effc6b5578be90bef93d96b3fceb1082a7c/docker-entrypoint.sh#L164) and then [started](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/eff90effc6b5578be90bef93d96b3fceb1082a7c/docker-entrypoint.sh#L172) again in normal (operational) mode, in which it listens both on UNIX and IP sockets:

```
LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

So, when the startup process is complete, you may connect to PostgreSQL using TCP connections, thus, entering into the container and running `psql -h localhost` succeeds.

Comment: I was bashing my head against the wall on this issue.
Thanks so much for this answer.